# Find total from inputs which are created by dynamically in angularJs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, input

I am creating group of inputs elements dynamically in angularJs. I want to find total,
Controller,

```
     $scope.itemElements = [
                {
                    "item": "item1",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "rate": 12.5
                },
                {
                    "item": "item2",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "rate": 12.5
                },
                {
                    "item": "item3",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "rate": 12.5
                }
            ];
$scope.calculateSum = function ()
        {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemElements.length; i++)
            {
                sum += $scope.itemElements["quantity"];
            }

            return sum;
        }
```

HTML,

```
 <tr ng-repeat="itemElemen in itemElements">
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="itemElemen.item" placeholder="Enter item" list="clientList"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="itemElemen.quantity" placeholder="Quantity"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="itemElemen.rate" placeholder="Rate"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" ng-value="itemElemen.quantity*itemElemen.rate"/></td>
            </tr>
```

Totatl,

```
 Total &nbsp;<span id="totalSum" ng-model="calculateSum()"></span>
```

It is not working,getting error is `[ngModel:nonassign]`, How can I do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code.

At first, `<span id="totalSum" ng-model="calculateSum()"></span>` - this code is not valid, here you get your error.
Better way is to output by value using 2-way-data-binding:

```
Total &nbsp;<span id="totalSum">{{calculateSum()}}</span>
```

After, in your function`calculateSum()` you have an error

```
  $scope.calculateSum = function ()
  {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemElements.length; i++)
    {
      sum += $scope.itemElements[i]["quantity"];
      //                         ^
      //                        Here
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

You need to refer to element from Array `$scope.itemElements`

After, better way is to use `input:number` instead of `input:text` for models which you really know are `Number`s

And the last, `input` for `Amount` is better to be `disabled`.

Finally, get next code.
**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="itemElemen in itemElements">
     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="itemElemen.item" placeholder="Enter item" list="clientList"/></td>
     <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="itemElemen.quantity" placeholder="Quantity"/></td>
     <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="itemElemen.rate" placeholder="Rate"/></td>
     <td><input type="number" disabled class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" ng-value="itemElemen.quantity*itemElemen.rate"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 Total &nbsp;<span id="totalSum">{{calculateSum()}}</span>
```

**JS**:

```
  $scope.itemElements = [
    {
      "item": "item1",
      "quantity": 2,
      "rate": 12.5
    },
    {
      "item": "item2",
      "quantity": 2,
      "rate": 12.5
    },
    {
      "item": "item3",
      "quantity": 2,
      "rate": 12.5
    }
  ];

  $scope.calculateSum = function ()
  {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemElements.length; i++)
    {
      sum += $scope.itemElements[i]["quantity"];
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/k2zrbNcMXwPhNcflV3yF?p=preview

Comment: It is working fine,very clear explanation too,Thank you for your time and effort. :)